# SQLite and Password Encryption, Decryption and Upload

Tags: android, database, sqlite, encryption, flash-builder

I am building a android application within flash builder, that will allow clients to use and access the database within the application, but blocking outside.

The case is to take an encrypted database(to stop client from accessing the information, outside the application), a password (to be hidden from the client) and upload it to a server. Of which the server will be able to use this password to decrypt the database, then I plan to use PHP to manipulate the data.

**What would be the best possible way to securely pass the SQLite database and the password in the upload phase?**

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPS for communicating with your server. That will automatically encrypt all traffic. Also keep in mind, that if the client (user) can access the data from the application, and the data is on the device, there is little you can do to keep them from copying and accessing the data outside of your app. As long as the password/encryption key is also on the device, all it will achieve is slow them down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a http API that your application will use. This API will enforce which operations are possible. So the client never sees the DB password, encrypted or not.

I don't really get what you're encrypting the db for. Are you trying to protect against the case where the server gets hacked?

Now other applications will be able to use this API, and it's impossible to stop them. You can just throw as much obfuscation at it as possible, and hope that crackers are too lazy.

Comment: The android app, will let the user add information to the database. The database from the start will be encrypted, every time the user wants to write to the database, it decrypts it, adds the information then again, encrypts it. The company I am working for do not wish the user to re-access to the data they input, as trends in data input become more valuble

Comment: Then store the database on the server. And create an add api call, for example by posting to `add.php`

Comment: But the whole point of storing the database on the app is to make it efficient, using it locally will provide efficient writing to the database, until you wish to finalize the client - uploading the database to the server, where it can be manipulated in its entirety

Comment: In that case, your problem simply boils down to obfuscation.